# Custom annotation on model field to encrypt and decrypt while storing to DB in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, java-annotations

I have a spring boot application and am a beginner with custom annotation. I want to introduce a custom annotation simillar to couchbase java sdk's @EncryptedField.
If I apply that annotation to a field in the model class, then that field has to be ecrypted when storing to db and decrypted when retriving back.
I am not clear which approach to take ? Should I using Spring AOP for this ? Any inputs to implement this will be really helpful

Comment: How do you access the db? Hibernate? Jdbc?

Comment: I am using spring-data-couchbase

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what persistence framework you're using.

For Mybatis, you can [add an incterceptor](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html)

like this

```
<plugins>       
    <plugin interceptor="com.XXX.XXXX.service.encryptinfo.MyInterceptor" />
</plugins>
```

Then implement it

```
    @Intercepts({
    @Signature(type=Executor.class,method="update",args={MappedStatement.class,Object.class}),
    @Signature(type=Executor.class,method="query",args={MappedStatement.class,Object.class,RowBounds.class,ResultHandler.class})
})
public class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor{

    // your logic here
    // write something that use reflection capture your custom annotaion of the entity and field
}
```